# Laravel memory size issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

Im getting this error message:

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4194312 bytes) in /...../vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:347
```

This is the function from where line 347 is found:

```
public function select($query, $bindings = [], $useReadPdo = true)
    {
        return $this->run($query, $bindings, function ($me, $query, $bindings) use ($useReadPdo) {
            if ($me->pretending()) {
                return [];
            }

            // For select statements, we'll simply execute the query and return an array
            // of the database result set. Each element in the array will be a single
            // row from the database table, and will either be an array or objects.
            $statement = $this->getPdoForSelect($useReadPdo)->prepare($query);

            $statement->execute($me->prepareBindings($bindings));

            $fetchMode = $me->getFetchMode();
            $fetchArgument = $me->getFetchArgument();
            $fetchConstructorArgument = $me->getFetchConstructorArgument();

            if ($fetchMode === PDO::FETCH_CLASS && ! isset($fetchArgument)) {
                $fetchArgument = 'StdClass';
                $fetchConstructorArgument = null;
            }

            return isset($fetchArgument)
                ? $statement->fetchAll($fetchMode, $fetchArgument, $fetchConstructorArgument)
                : $statement->fetchAll($fetchMode);
        });
    }
```

This happens randomly so it is hard to debug. Is there a fix for this ? What should I try ? Thx

Comment: this is not the problem with this file. the problem is with a query in your code which generates a loop or a php code which create a loop of sql queries thus you are getting this error

Comment: break that return statement into a separate function.. as a recommendation more than anything

Comment: what about `DB::disableQueryLog();` will it work ?

Comment: @Chester I believe the issue is with the memory not being freed up - PHP isn't the greatest at handling memory, unset array vars etc. after using them in the function to free it up, or look into the garbage collector